# GTK ignores any type of window positioning

Tags: gtk, splash-screen, window-position

I've been trying to position a splash screen at the center of the screen.  In Windows, such a request is easy using SetWindowPos and a bit of geometric arithmetic.  I found out that all requests to move a window are ignored by the windowing manager.  So my question is, how come I see so many applications with pretty splash screens properly centered?  I started with GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL BTW and just switch to popup trying a few things.  Setting the gravity and position do not fail, they are just ignored.  Even defined in a .glade file, the window is ignored.

```
{
    GtkWidget *pNewWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(pNewWindow), 0, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(pNewWindow);
    while (gtk_events_pending())
        gtk_main_iteration();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(pNewWindow, width, height);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(pNewWindow), FALSE);
//  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(pNewWindow), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(pNewWindow), FALSE);
//  gtk_window_set_gravity(GTK_WINDOW(pNewWindow), GDK_GRAVITY_CENTER);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(pNewWindow), 0, 0);
    while (gtk_events_pending())
        gtk_main_iteration();
    return pNewWindow;
}
```

Comment: OK, I'm tried setting the gravity, I've tried making the gravity static and moving the window to a set point, I tried setting it's position as center always, nothing works.  It's being to sink in that it is absolutely IMPOSSIBLE to position a window programmatically in GTK.  If I'm wrong, please let me know.  Otherwise, my Linux development experiment is coming to an end.

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: no.  But it's moot for me as I am no longer with the company